# Facebook UI method feed is not displaying picture on wall post

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following function to post on users' wall. Every thing works fine, I checked and rechecked with the actual URL https://mydomain.com/fb/uploads/image.jpg of the $post[image], but when I envoke the function, post is successfully made on wall but there is no picture.

```
function postToFeed() {
   var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: '<?php echo $post[link]; ?>',
      picture: '<?php echo $post[image];?>',
      name: '<?php echo $post[name]; ?>',
      caption: '<?php echo $post[caption]; ?>',
      description: '<?php echo $post[description]; ?>'
    };

    function callback(response) {
       alert("Picture Shared!!!");
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```